# Async MQ ping-pong

Tags: python, go, rabbitmq

I have two sender-receivers. The first is written on Python and the second is on Golang. I used official sources of RabbitMQ documentation [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html) and [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-go.html).

Python code:

```
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body='hello')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)
    num = int(body[5:])
    num = num + 1
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body='hello'+str(num))

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='hello',
                      no_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()

connection.close()
```

Golang receiver-sender:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s: %s", msg, err)
    }
}

func main() {
    conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
    failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
    defer conn.Close()

    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
    defer ch.Close()

    q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
        "hello", // name
        false,   // durable
        false,   // delete when unused
        false,   // exclusive
        false,   // no-wait
        nil,     // arguments
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to declare a queue")

    msgs, err := ch.Consume(
        q.Name, // queue
        "",     // consumer
        true,   // auto-ack
        false,  // exclusive
        false,  // no-local
        false,  // no-wait
        nil,    // args
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to register a consumer")


    forever := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for d := range msgs {
            log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
            s := string(d.Body)
            num, _ := strconv.ParseInt(s[5:], 0, 64)
            num++
            body := fmt.Sprintf("hello%d", num)
            err = ch.Publish(
                "",     // exchange
                q.Name, // routing key
                false,  // mandatory
                false,  // immediate
                amqp.Publishing {
                ContentType: "text/plain",
                Body:        []byte(body),
                })
            failOnError(err, "Failed to publish a message")
        }
    }()

    log.Printf(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C")
    <-forever
}
```

What can be improved here? May be I can use non-default `exchange` here? Are both pieces of my code working asynchronously?